# What the difference between new-netroute and route add?

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, routing

I have Windows Server 2012R2 with VPN Server (RRAS)

When some user connected I want setup routing to his network.

Everything work fine when I use route add, but when I use New-NetRoute routing don't works as needed.

For example (networks 192.168.110.0/24 and 192.168.111.0/24. both accessible via connection when I use route add command)

```
PS C:\tools> Get-NetRoute
ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                              -------                                     ----------- -----------
22      192.168.111.0/24                               192.168.99.199                                     1 ActiveStore
22      192.168.110.0/24                               192.168.99.199                                     1 ActiveStore
```

Routing to network 192.168.110.0/24 was added with command

```
route add 192.168.110.0/24 192.168.99.199
```

Routing to network 192.168.111.0/24 was added with command

```
New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 192.168.111.0/24 -NextHop 192.168.99.199 -PolicyStore ActiveStore -RouteMetric 1 -InterfaceIndex 22
```

When I trying to ping host on network I receive next output:

```
PS C:\tools> ping 192.168.110.1 -n 1

Pinging 192.168.110.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.110.1: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 192.168.110.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 61ms, Maximum = 61ms, Average = 61ms
PS C:\tools> ping 192.168.111.1 -n 1

Pinging 192.168.111.1 with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.

Ping statistics for 192.168.111.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
```

So when I use route add I have no problems and everything works as needed, but when I use New-NetRoute I have problems with **General failure** error.

Comment: `route add` adds the route to IP stack routing table. `New-NetRoute` (it seems) adds the route to RRAS table. Check does the route added via `New-NetRoute` is visible in `cmd - route print` output...

Comment: @Akina: Hmm, so how _do_ you add live IP routes via PowerShell cmdlets?

Comment: I have detected those "difference" (routes addition via `route add` and via MMC-RRAS) when Windows Server 2000 was the most recent OS. From that time I do not use routing table edition other than `route.exe` - I like when I can predict the result.

Comment: @Akina output of route print same for both routes and route added via New-NetRoute is visible with route print.

Comment: @grawity I also saw this problem a couple of years ago... but now time to play with this problem again. Concerning how to add live IP routes via PowerShell cmdlets... just use call to route.exe... I do it this way.